# stuck loading external html into jquery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-apps-script

Here is some of the code that I have.

```
     function addLoad(){

     //$("#dialog-modal")load('truckload.html').dialog({modal:true});
     $("#dialog-modal").dialog(
     {
     width: 600,
     height: 400,

     open: function(event, ui)
     {
     $(this).load('truckload.html');
     //$("#dialog-modal").load(url).dialog({modal:true});
        var textarea = $('<textarea style="height: 276px;">');
        $(textarea).redactor({
            focus: true,
            autoresize: false,

            initCallback: function()
            {
                this.set('<p>Lorem...</p>');
            }

            });
            }
            });
     }

</script>
<div id="dialog-modal" title="Add Information to calendar" style="display: none;"></div>
```

AddLoad is called by a button and truckload.html is a file included in my google script project.  All of the commented out lines are different ways I have attempted to make this work.

My goal is that when addLoad is called that a dialog opens and displays the truckload page information.  What am I doing wrong?  Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,

Loren

Comment: Getting any errors in your browser console?

Comment: @teatimer not that I've seen.  But nothing seems to show when the dialog loads either.  I added comments prior to and following the dialog code and they both show with no errors between.

Answer (score 0):

build the popup first, then call the popup by a link or button. see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jrscdrgL/):

Be sure you have the right jquery resources:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Code JS

```
 var webPage = "http://www.cbc.ca";

 var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
           .html('<iframe style="border: 0px; " src="' + webPage + '" width="80%"   [enter link description here][2]height="80%"></iframe>')
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
               height: 650,
               width: 600,
               title: "Add Information to calendar"
           });
 $("#popup").on("click", function(){
  $dialog.dialog('open');
 });
```

Comment: I've tried running this and I'm getting an error:  TypeError: Invalid value used as weak map key

Comment: I did get the dialog to display but the page does not.  uggg

Comment: what version of jquery are you running?

Comment: here is what is declared on the page:  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Comment: updated the answer--Fiddle works, so maybe something else in your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to call this from an HtmlService, it would look something like this:

**Code.gs** file

```
// render initial html page
function doGet(event){
 return HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('index').evaluate(); 
}

// call from click on page (or if using UiApp)
function addLoad(){
  try{
    // get the html content from the truckload.html page and return it to the showModal                function
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('truckload').getContent();
  }catch(err){
    Logger.log(err.lineNumber + ' - ' + err);
  }
}
```

**index.html** file

```
<div id='popup'>
Click Me
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#popup").click(function(){
   // call to script runner
google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(showModal).addLoad();
  });

});

 function showModal(htmlContent){
   var $dialog = $('<div style="border:2px solid black;background-color:#B6B6B4;"></div>')
           .html(htmlContent)
           .dialog({
               autoOpen: false,
               modal: true,
              height: 350,
               width: 600,
               title: "truckload"
           });
    $dialog.dialog('open');
  }
</script>
```

Finally the **truckload.html** file 
(whatever html you are looking to render)

here's a crude example:

[Truckload modal](https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbw7c8fiWsA5Y1lsgA_4Wl4lUMnfePrpK8OvaUIZ1Sin4fQgkmL8/exec)

Comment: Doesn't show up in the posting above, but in the index.html file I had used <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>, but it does also work with the CDNs you had posted: <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>